# What's the algebraic property where you can flip the fractions in an equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, fractions

Earlier in algebra, we spent over 20 minutes trying to figure out

$$ \frac{1}{R_1} + \frac{1}{R_2} = \frac{1}{R_e} \,\,\,\, \text{solve for }R_2 $$

when the teacher said "What you start out with is the same as what you learned in pre-algebra

$$
\frac{1}{R_1} + \frac{1}{R_2} = \frac{1}{R_e}
$$

subtract $\frac{1}{R_1}$ from both sides:

$$\frac{1}{R_2} = \frac{1}{R_e} - \frac{1}{R_1}$$

and then the math gods said 'you may flip as long as all are flipped'"

$$R_2 = R_e - R_1$$

What is the name of this algebraic property?

(Sorry, I couldn't find any good tags for use here.)

Comment: I'm afraid it's not true. That's probably why you couldn't remember it

Comment: Whatever math God told you that is wrong =]

Comment: @David Mitra Be careful, sometimes students misinterpret the instructors =P

Comment: The property is named "error".  Sometimes called a variation of the freshman's dream.  In general $\frac{1}{\frac{1}{R_1}-\frac{1}{R_2}} = \frac{R_1-R_2}{R_1 R_2}.$

Comment: There is no such algebraic property. Now both sides of an equation can be reciprocated (for values of variables such that the sides of the equation are not zero). However, that is not an algebraic property, but simply the consequence that both sides of an equation denote the same number, and the same operation is done to that number on both sides. Algebraic properties usually tell us that certain *apparently different* patterns of operations are actually equivalent.

Comment: @deinst: I thought freshman's dream was $(a+b)^n = a^n + b^n$ . How is this a variation to it?

Comment: @Nick - I think the "generalized freshman's dream" would be: All operations are linear. This certainly fits into that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can flip if you flip correctly. Flipping both sides of

$$\frac{1}{R_2} = \frac{1}{R_e} - \frac{1}{R_1}$$

gives you

$$ R_2 = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{R_e} - \frac{1}{R_1}}$$

Well, that's not quite right: more pedantically, flipping both sides gives

$$ \frac{1}{\frac{1}{R_2}} = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{R_e} - \frac{1}{R_1}}$$

but we know that the left hand side of this is the same thing as $R_2$. (at least in the current setting, where $R_2$ is known to be nonzero)

Answer (score 13):

This is not an algebraic property, because it is not true.

For example, let $R_2=R_1=2$ and $R_e =1$. Then, $$\frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{1} - \frac{1}{2}$$
but
$$2 \neq 1 - 2$$

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can “flip”, so long as the two sides are single fractions: from
$$
\frac{1}{R_2}=\frac{R_1-R_e}{R_1R_e}
$$
you can rightly deduce
$$
R_2=\frac{R_1R_e}{R_1-R_e}
$$

Note that, in general,
$$
\frac{R_1R_e}{R_1-R_e}\ne R_e-R_1
$$
Indeed the equality would imply
$$
R_1R_e=-R_e^2+2R_1R_e-R_1^2
$$
or
$$
R_1^2-R_1R_e+R_e^2=0
$$
Since your numbers are by hypothesis non zero, this would imply
$$
\left(\frac{R_1}{R_e}\right)^2-\frac{R_1}{R_e}+1=0
$$
or, setting $t=R_1/R_e$, $t^2-t+1=0$. This equality is not true for every real $t$. So your conclusion is ***really*** wrong.

Answer (score 3):

You can't just flip all willy-nilly.
If what you said was true, then the resistance of electrical circuits in series and parallel connections would be the same! That just isn't true.

$$\frac{1}{R_1} + \frac{1}{R_2} + \frac{1}{R_3} + \dots + \frac{1}{R_n}\mathbf{\neq} \frac{1}{R_1 + R_2 + R_3 + \dots + R_n}$$
Fastest way to see this is by setting $R_1 = R_ 2 = \dots = R_n = R$ (say)

Does it feel like $\frac{n}{R} $ and $\frac{1}{nR}$ are the same? 

Now, you see. You must either change your math gods or listen to them more carefully.

The flipping property is called the **Invertendo**:
$$\frac{a}{b} = \frac{c}{d} \iff \frac{b}{a} = \frac{d}{c} $$

There are *many ways* you can realize it and I leave it as an exercise to you to try.

The simplest way is by raising both sides of the equation to $-1$ :

$$\frac{a}{b} = \frac{c}{d} 
\implies \left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^{-1} = \left(\frac{c}{d}\right)^{-1} 
\implies \frac{a^{-1}}{b^{-1}} = \frac{c^{-1}}{d^{-1}} 
\implies \frac{1}{a} \cdot \frac{b}{1} = \frac{1}{c} \cdot \frac{d}{1} \implies \frac{b}{a} = \frac{d}{c}$$

---

The following is the best approach to your question:

$$
\frac{1}{R_1} + \frac{1}{R_2} = \frac{1}{R_e}\\
\implies \frac{1}{R_2} = \frac{1}{R_e} - \frac{1}{R_1} 
= \overbrace{\frac{R_1 - R_e}{R_1 R_e}}^{\text{Taking LCM}} \\
\implies \underbrace{R_2 = \frac{R_1 R_e}{R_1 - R_e}}_{\text{Applying Invertendo}}$$